# Remove outer Object from certain key but keep inner objects

Tags: javascript

Hi I have the following object:

```
{
  "position": {
    "json": {
      "left": "57px",
      "top": "79px"
    }
  },
}
```

It contains several other keys like `size` etc...

How can I get rid of the `"json"` without deleting the inner content so that my result looks like

```
{
  "position": {
    "left": "57px",
    "top": "79px"
  },
}
```

I need a way to remove every key that has a string `"json"` as content without removing the containing objects.

Comment: Loop over the inner objects keys, add them to the outer object. When you're done, delete the outer object by it's key. There is no one-liner to say "delete the outer object key and just reassign all it's child key-values to it's parent object". Whatever happened to trying it and asking for help when you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible fix, update the object with contents of `json` as a direct `value` pair using `Object.assign(object,thingToUpdate)` and then `delete` the `json` key:

```js
let objects = {
  "position": {
    "json": {
      "left": "57px",
      "top": "79px"
    }
  },
  "size": {
    "json": {
      "left": "57px",
      "top": "79px"
    }
  }
}

function removeJSONString(obj) {
  // store all keys of this object for later use
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);
  // for each key update the "json" key
  keys.map(key => {
    // updates only if it has "json"
    if (obj[key].hasOwnProperty("json")) {
      // assign the current obj a new field with "json" value pair
      Object.assign(obj[key], obj[key]["json"]);
      // delete "json" key from this object
      delete obj[key]["json"];
    }
  })
  // updated all fields of obj
  return obj;
}

console.log(removeJSONString(objects));
```