# Using a JavaScript object fom parsed JSON with variable root element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to write JavaScript to use parsed JSON, however the JSONP has a variable root, like this:

```
{"AAPL":{"quote":{"symbol":"AAPL","change":-3.34}},
 "FB":{"quote":{"symbol":"FB","change":1.03}},
 "TSLA":{"quote":{"symbol":"TSLA","change":2.9}}}


var stocks = ['AAPL', 'FB', 'TSLA'];
var stocksUrl = stocks.join(',');
var url = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=' + stocksUrl + '&types=quote';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
```

After parsing with jquery, I can reference the JavaScript object such as:
`console.log(JSON.stringify(data.AAPL.quote.symbol));
}`

However, since the length of the object is variable and the root element is variable, I am not sure how to use a for loop to iterate through the symbol and change elements.

My question is how to remove a variable root element and keep the sub-elements so that the object afterword would be referenced such that quote became the root element, ie:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.quote.symbol));
}
```

I have tried [Remove outer Object from certain key but keep inner objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372044/remove-outer-object-from-certain-key-but-keep-inner-objects) but that solution is for a known element name. Can I do something similar with a variable object name? Or is there a better way to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "variable root"? There doesn't seem to be a root item, there are just 3 properties in the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, in this case, you don't need to use the hardcore key name

```
var data = {"AAPL":{"quote":{"symbol":"AAPL","change":-3.34}},
             "FB":{"quote":{"symbol":"FB","change":1.03}},
         "TSLA":{"quote":{"symbol":"TSLA","change":2.9}}};

var keysArr= Object.keys(data);
for(var i=0;i<keysArr.length;i++){
    console.log(data[keysArr[i]].quote.symbol)
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.values();` is a method that will give you an array of just the values of an object.

So, this object

```
{
    "fb": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    },
    "google": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    },
    "ig": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    }
}
```

Could be turned into this:

```
var stuff_array = Object.values(stuff);
// turns into this
stuff_array = [
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    },
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    },
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    }
]
```

So now you have an array, and you can loop over it with any one of about 10 different looping methods (.forEach, .map, .reduce, for loop, while loop).

Comment: I like this idea as well and will incorporate it into my script. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify [the example you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372044/remove-outer-object-from-certain-key-but-keep-inner-objects) to work for you.

```
function removeJSONString(obj) {
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);

    keys.map(key => {
      Object.assign(obj[key], obj[key].quote);
      delete obj[key].quote;
    });

  return obj;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/884396/) you can play around with to get what you intended.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I like the idea and tried to hack from the example with no luck. I'm not getting any console output from the fiddle.

Comment: @Bob I updated fiddle to show response in html.